# Issues with time formats in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am facing some issues with time formats in django.

My models DateTimeField is using auto_now to store datetime and I am trying to filter data using this datetimefield.
The input datetime which I am using to comapre is in differenr format like `2016-1-5T5:00:00` and datetime stored in djnago models is default django format since I am using `auto_now`.
The error I am getting is as follows :

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField MyModel.modified_at received a naive datetime (2016-01-05 05:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

So I guess I need to convert the input time into django suitable format.
Any idea how I can compare these two dates so that my query can filter correct data.

Comment: @AmalTs I ahve tgried that part but when I'll do this `datetime.datetime(my_time_inut)`  I'll get error saying str not allowed

Comment: But are you using from `django.utils import timezone`?

Comment: @AmalTs yes from utils

Comment: @user5594493: `datetime(my_time_input)` is a different question. You can ask a separate question e.g., "how to get a timezone-aware datetime object given `my_time_input`". Make sure to describe what `my_time_input` is (is it a string? is it a returned value from an API call? etc).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes I am getting input from API call and its format is mentioned in question -> 2016-1-5T5:00:00

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the word "format": does it mean `type(my_time_input)` is `str`? `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField MyModel.modified_at received a naive datetime` indicates that you already have a `datetime` object (`type(obj) == datetime`, not `str`). `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` (e.g., due to `datetime('2016-1-5T5:00:00')`) is a different issue. If you get `TypeError` then you should fix it first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a timezone aware datetime? e.g.

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

You can make it like this:

```
import pytz
timezone_aware_time = pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 20, 8, 7, 127325))
```

To get your string into a compliant format and then give it a timezone, do this:

```
import datetime from datetime
datetime.strptime('2016-1-5T5:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

So, altogether:

```
import pytz
import datetime from datetime
timezone_aware_time = pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(datetime.strptime('2016-1-5T5:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

For reference, auto_now is in timezone UTC.

Comment: I have tried that part but when I'll do this datetime.datetime(my_time_inut) I'll get error saying str not allowed -> an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Can you post what my_time_inut is? Also, did you mean inut or input?

Comment: it is input and the format is `2016-1-5T5:00:00` . I am getting this input from smartphone

Comment: do this:
import pytz
pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 5, 5, 0, 0))

Comment: but the question is how to convert 2016-1-5T5:00:00 -> 2016, 1, 5, 5, 0, 0 ?

Comment: from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('2016-1-5T5:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')